# Prove that the roots of $x^3=1$ add to 0

Tags: complex-numbers

How could I prove the roots of the equation $x^3=1$ add up to $0$?
Geometrically it is not difficult to see they'll add to $0$, but when working it out algebraically I don't know how to add $e^{2\pi i/3}+e^{4\pi i/3}$.

Comment: Hint: $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$

Answer (score 3):

For any monic degree-$n$ complex polynomial
$$
f(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0\\
=(x-r_0)(x-r_1)\cdots(x-r_n)
$$
where the $r_i$ are the $n$ roots (possibly with repeats), we have
$$
a_{n-1}=-(r_1+r_2+\cdots+r_n)
$$
And in your case, you're after the sum of the three roots of the monic degree-$3$ polynomial $x^3-1$.

Comment: +$1$; cf. [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\omega$ be a primitive third root of unity. We have $\omega^3=1$. Then by the finite geometric series
$$
1+\omega+\omega^2=\frac{\omega^3-1}{\omega-1}=0.
$$
We do not even need to use $e^{i\theta}$. But $1,\omega,\omega^2$ are just the roots of $X^3-1=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\omega\neq 1$ is a root of $x^3=1$, then $\omega^2\neq\omega$ is also a root of $x^3=1$ because $(\omega^2)^3 = (\omega^3)^2 = 1$. The same applies to $\omega^3$. The polynomial $x^3=1$ is of order 3 and has 3 distinct roots. The sum of roots is then $\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3$.

The root $\omega\neq1$ is similar to the primitive element of a finite group and its powers constitute all the distinct roots.

Look closely at
$\omega(\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3) = \omega^2 + \omega^3 +\omega^4 = \omega^2 + \omega^3 +1\cdot\omega = \omega+\omega^2+\omega^3$.

If follows that either $\omega = 1$ or $\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3 = 0$.

Since $\omega \neq 1$, it leads to $\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3 = 0$.

Comment: I don't understand why if ω is a root, then ω2 will be also a root (how do we know (ω2)3=1?). On the other hand, why do you compute ω(ω+ω2+ω3) and after it, substitute ω4 for 1·ω? Thank you very much.

Comment: @albertvvila if $\omega$ is a root of $x^3=1$, it means that $\omega^3=1$. To verify whether the square of $\omega$, i.e., $\omega^2$, is a root of $x^3=1$, we just need to see if $(\omega^2)^3=1$ is true. Now look at $(\omega^2)^3=(\omega^3)^2$. Remember $\omega$ is a root, we have $\omega^3=1$. I hope you get it.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Just one last thing, how can we know either (ω+ω2+ω3)=0 or ω=0? If isolating ω from the equation  ω(ω+ω2+ω3)=ω+ω2+ω3, I get ω=1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @albertvvila thanks for spotting the error. I've edited the answer. Now it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\omega, \omega^2, 1$ be the three distinct cube roots of unity. Then, we have

$$\omega(\omega^2 + \omega + 1) = \omega^3 + \omega^2 + \omega = 1 + \omega^2 + \omega$$

Since $\omega \neq 1$, it follows that $$\omega^2 + \omega + 1=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Note $e^{4\pi i/3}= e^{4\pi i/3-i2\pi} = e^{-2\pi i/3} $. Thus, the sum is

$$1+ e^{2\pi i/3}+e^{4\pi i/3} =1+ e^{2\pi i/3}+ e^{-2\pi i/3}=1+2\cos(2\pi/3)=1+2(-1/2)=0
$$

Answer (score 0):

You calculated the roots already, so

$$e^{2\pi i/3} + e^{4\pi i/3} + 1 = \cos 2\pi/3 + i \sin 2\pi/3 + \cos 4\pi/3 + i \sin 4\pi/3 + 1$$
$$= -\frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} -\frac{1}{2} - i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + 1=0.$$